# unexpected result using jaxb eclipselink2.2 with cdata

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

```xml
<ITEM>
     <PRODUCT_NAME>IT'S ALL ABOUT YOU-LG:9&quot;H RUBY GATHERNG VASE,RD ROSE,LIME GRN CARN,PURP STOCK,LAV POMS,ATHOS POM,SEAFOAM STATICE,SALAL</PRODUCT_NAME>
     <PRODUCT_CODE>90949L</PRODUCT_CODE>
     <PRODUCT_TYPE>FPT</PRODUCT_TYPE>
     <PRODUCT_CAT>Floral</PRODUCT_CAT>
     <ALIAS_NAME>IT'S ALL ABOUT YOU(TM) - LARGE</ALIAS_NAME>
     <DELIVERY_DATE>10/11/2012</DELIVERY_DATE>
     <FLEX_DATE></FLEX_DATE>
     <FLEX_TEXT></FLEX_TEXT>
     <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
     <PRICE>69.99</PRICE>
     <CARD_MESSAGE>IT'S ALL ABOUT YOU...
```

when i dont add `@XmlCDATA` annotation i am getting only one product name element. But when i use cdata annotation i am getting duplicate.One with cdata and without cdata

Answer (score 0):

By default a [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation will expect annotations to be on the get (or set) methods.  If you annotate a field this can cause a property to appear multiple times in the XML representation.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/XmlAccessorType
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/cdata-cdata-run-run-data-run.html